# Passing the URL to typeahead.js via data-url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js

I have Twitter Typeahead.js working well but I wanted to make it a little more modular (DRY!) by passing a 'prefetch' or 'remote' URL via a data-parameter.

So my markup is:

```
<input class="typeahead" data-url="http://campaigndashboard.dev/ajax/con" />
```

I had written in the JQuery:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: $(this).data('name'),
    limit: 100,

    remote: { /* This works! */
         url: 'http://campaigndashboard.dev/ajax/con?q=%QUERY',
    },
    remote: {  /* This doesn't */
         url: $(this).data('url') + '?q=%QUERY',
    }
});
```

I've used this way of passing variables before, but I'm stumped as to why this does not work. I'll also want to append the %QUERY if its a 'remote' but not if its 'prefetch' -any thoughts on that?

NOTE: I'm not trying to amend the %QUERY part of the URL, so i discounted the replace() function.

Very new to Jquery so please feel free to tell me all this things I'm doing wrong!

Thanks in advance

Al

Comment: Just to clarify, I have included both the 'remote' lines here, but in the actual code, i used one or the other

Comment: did you get an error in the javascript console?

Comment: Hi @Pascamel. Thanks for the quick response. No errors, and I tried to  include a console.log() but that didn;t log:
`.on('typeahead:opened',function(){
         console.log('remote=', remote);})`

Answer (score 2):

Better still:

```js
$(".typeahead").each(function(){
      $(this).typeahead({
          name: $(this).name,
          remote: $(this).data('source')         
      });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! Much neater.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED IT!!**

I needed to create some kind of function to gather the data-attributes before invoking typeahead.

This is what I did (if anyone else is wondering):

```
$('.typeahead').each( function() {
    createTypeahead( this );
} );

function createTypeahead( selector ){
  var t = $( selector );
  //get all the data-atributes from the input tag
  var source = $(t).data('source');
  //etc etc (get as many vars as you like here)

  var retval = t.typeahead({
    prefetch: source,    //This is the var from above
    //etc etc
  });

  return retval;
}
```

I'm sure this isn't the most elegant way - feel free to correct this/improve it in the comments

Your markup (HTML) would look like this:

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" data-source="http://{yoursite.com}/url/to/your/json" >
```

Hope this helped someone.

Comment: PS. In case you were as new as I was to this, then to get this working, just add the class='typeahead' to the inputs you want a typahead to appear on. Don;t forget to specify a data-source="url", as there is no fallback in this example.

`<input type="text" class="typeahead" data-source="http://{yoursite.com}/url/to/your/json" >`

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I can't believe this isn't directly supported. I like your approach, but it won't work if a typeahead input is added after the #each loop is run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out the "proper"(?) answer. In order to dynamically determine the url at click time, you need to use the source syntax, where the first argument is a map of options, and the 2nd to nth arguments are maps of DataSet options.

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({}, {
  source: function(){
    var url = this.$el.parents(".twitter-typeahead").find(".typeahead").data().url
    ....ajax to your url...
  }
})
```